# Django channels consumer not receiving data

Tags: python, django, asynchronous, websocket, django-channels

I'm trying to write a websocket consumer that gets all unread notifications as well as all notifications being created while the client is still connected to the websocket.

I'm able to connect to the consumer and it's showing me all active notifications. The problem is that it doesn't show me new notifications when they're being created and sent from the model's save method.

consumers.py

```
class NotificationConsumer(WebsocketConsumer):
    def get_notifications(self, user):
        new_followers = NotificationSerializer(Notification.objects.filter(content=1), many=True)

        notifs = {
            "new_followers": new_followers.data
        }

        return {
            "count": sum(len(notif) for notif in notifs.values()),
            "notifs": notifs
        }

    def connect(self):
        user = self.scope["user"]

        if user:
            self.channel_name = user.username
            self.room_group_name = 'notification_%s' % self.channel_name

            notification = self.get_notifications(self.scope["user"])
            print("Notification", notification)

            self.accept()
            return self.send(text_data=json.dumps(notification))
        
        self.disconnect(401)
    
    async def disconnect(self, close_code):
        await self.channel_layer.group_discard(
            self.room_group_name,
            self.channel_name
        )
    
    async def receive(self, text_data):
        text_data_json = json.loads(text_data)
        count = text_data_json['count']
        notification_type = text_data_json['notification_type']
        notification = text_data_json['notification']
        print(text_data_json)

        await self.channel_layer.group_send(
            self.room_group_name,
            {
                "type": "receive",
                "count": count,
                "notification_type": notification_type,
                "notification": notification
            }
        )
```

models.py

```
class Notification(models.Model):
    content = models.CharField(max_length=200, choices=NOTIFICATION_CHOICES, default=1)
    additional_info = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True)
    seen = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    users_notified = models.ManyToManyField("core.User", blank=True)
    user_signaling = models.ForeignKey("core.User", on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="user_signaling")

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if self._state.adding:
            super(Notification, self).save(*args, **kwargs)

        else:
            notif = Notification.objects.filter(seen=False)
            data = {
                "type": "receive",
                "count": len(notif),
                "notification_type": self.content,
                "notification": self.additional_info
            }

            channel_layer = get_channel_layer()
            for user in self.users_notified.all():
                async_to_sync(channel_layer.group_send(
                        f"notification_{user.username}",
                        data
                    )
                )
                print(channel_layer)
```

I'm checking for `self._state.adding` so it'll only send the websocket message when `users_notified` have already been added after the model was created.

example use case:

```
notif = Notification.objects.create(
      content=1, 
      user_signaling=user,
      additional_info=f"{user.username} just followed you!"
)
notif.users_notified.add(other_user)
notif.save()
```

Answer (score 2):

What generally works for me is to use signals, in your case, you could use a post_save signal instead of overriding the model save().

```py
channel_layer = get_channel_layer()


@receiver(post_save, sender=Notification)
def notification_on_create(sender, instance, created, **kwargs) -> None:
    _, _ = sender, kwargs
    if created:
        return None
    notif = Notification.objects.filter(seen=False)
    data = {
                "type": "receive",
                "count": len(notif),
                "notification_type": instance.content,
                "notification": instance.additional_info
            }
    for user in self.users_notified.all():
        async_to_sync(channel_layer.group_send(
                f"notification_{user.username}", data))
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I managed to get it working by not overriding the `self.channel_name` property with `user.username`. For whatever reason django-channels can't handle having custom `self.channel_name` properties set. Changing up the variable did it for me